# Wrong year for 1st January 2022

Tags: angular

I'm using Angular's own date pipe to format dates.
However I've discovered an error when it comes to a specific date: **1st January 2022**.

If you visit = https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qrnysm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

You'll see I have 2 dates:
`2022-01-01` and `2022-01-02`. In the template they are both using `| date:'dd/MM/YYYY':'GMT'`.
But the first date formats to = `01/01/2021` (wrong year) but the second date formats to `02/01/2022` (correct year).

Has anyone else experienced this?
Here is the code from the stackblitz:

```
formattedIssueDate1: Date = new Date("2022-01-01T00:00:00Z");
formattedIssueDate2: Date = new Date("2022-01-02T00:00:00Z");

<p>
  This is date 1: {{formattedIssueDate1 | date:'dd/MM/YYYY':'GMT'}}
</p>
<p>
  This is date 2: {{formattedIssueDate2 | date:'dd/MM/YYYY':'GMT'}}
</p>
```

Comment: Please share more details, like the code to reproduce the problem, and your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: Seems like a bug. `1998-01-01` gets printed correctly, but then `1999-01-01` gets printed as `1st January 1998` again. You can report it on Angular's GitHub issue tracker.

Comment: Btw this question should NOT have been closed. Look at how many people it has helped. That is all

Comment: @AndrewHoward this is re-opned now, BUT please add the essential code from your stackblitz, since that link might get lost in future

Comment: Indeed, I am tempted to vote to close this question again; it simply does not have enough information in the question itself to answer it. People can still access and be helped by closed questions, questioners and answerers may not get rep from votes put on them. If only the OP would simply copy and paste the code from that StackBlitz to their question, as only they have the right to do...

Comment: @HereticMonkey I have now pasted in the code from stackblitz. Hope that's all fine.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The “yyyy” represents the calendar year of the date while the “YYYY” represents the year of the week..
Your format need to be written as small case for years

```
  This is date 1: {{formattedIssueDate1 | date:'dd/MM/yyyy':'GMT'}}
```

Answer (score 5):

As per Angular [date pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe#custom-format-options) docs
the format should be

`date:'dd/MM/yyyy':'GMT'`

- Year = y, yy, yyy, yyyy
- Week-numbering year = Y, YY, YYY, YYYY